# Is it possible to access an iframe contents within Jest test

Tags: iframe, jestjs

Is it possible to access `iframe` contents within Jest test?
This is my approach. Unfortunately no luck in there. `headerElement` is undefined.

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
  <iframe
    class="js-iframe"
    src="https://example.com"
    onload="${iframeLoaded()}"
  ></iframe>
  <script></script>
`;

function iframeLoaded() {
  const headerElement = domMethodsService.getElement<HTMLIFrameElement>('.js-iframe')?.contentWindow?.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')
  
  expect(headerElement).toBe('Example Domain');
  doneCallback();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `iframeLoaded()`function before iframe loads it's content. Try creating the `iframe` element using `document.createElement`:

```
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.classList.add("js-iframe");
  iframe.onload = iframeLoaded;
  iframe.src = "https://example.com";
  
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  function iframeLoaded() {
    const headerElement = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('h1'); //--> getElementsByTagName will return more than one element
    expect(headerElement).toBe('Example Domain');
    doneCallback();
  }
```

By default, `jsdom` will not load any sub-resources like iframes. You can load such resources by setting `resources: "usable"`, which will load all usable resources.

**jest.config.js**

```
"testEnvironmentOptions": { "resources": "usable" }
```